# Appropriate Location of saving secret key

Tags: java, keystore

Could anyone please let me know or clear my doubt where exactly the key store should be placed while working in project.

I know the java is maintain key store in secuirty/cancerts & cancerts is trutstore & in keystore they have provided the key-value pair for secret key.

Now I want to store my custom keystore (In that keystore contain secret key with key-value pair), So where I m going to store ?

is it in the project itself with the .keystore file as like some other .properties file ??  or any other location ??

Do I need to assign certificate for that keystore if yes. how can I pragmatically ??

below is the code which is generated test.keystore in project itself ...

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String fileWithKeyStore = "test.keystore";
    KeyStore keyStore = JKSTest.createKeyStore(fileWithKeyStore, "pwdForKeyStoreFile");

    storeKeyInKeyStore(keyStore, fileWithKeyStore);
    // retriveKeyFromKeyStore(keyStore);

}

public static void storeKeyInKeyStore(KeyStore keyStore, String fileWithKeyStore) throws Exception {

    System.out.println(keyStore.getType()); // JCEKS

    /** Storing in key value format like map but with password */
    SecretKey secretKey = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES").generateKey(); // JWT-Key

    keyStore.setEntry("map_key", new KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry(secretKey),
            new PasswordProtection("pwdForMapEntry".toCharArray()));

    keyStore.store(new FileOutputStream(fileWithKeyStore), "pwdForStoringFile".toCharArray());
    System.out.println("Stored Key:\t" + secretKey);

}

public static void retriveKeyFromKeyStore(KeyStore keyStore)
        throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnrecoverableEntryException, KeyStoreException {

    KeyStore.Entry entry = keyStore.getEntry("map_key", new PasswordProtection("pwdForMapEntry".toCharArray()));
    SecretKey keyFound = ((KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry) entry).getSecretKey();
    System.out.println("Found Key:\t" + keyFound);

}


public static KeyStore createKeyStore(String fileName, String pw) throws Exception {
    File file = new File(fileName);

    final KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JCEKS");
    if (file.exists()) {
        // .keystore file already exists => load it
        keyStore.load(new FileInputStream(file), pw.toCharArray());
        System.out.println("Existing .keystore file loaded!"+file.getAbsolutePath());
    } else {
        // .keystore file not created yet => create it
        keyStore.load(null, null);
        keyStore.store(new FileOutputStream(fileName), pw.toCharArray());
        System.out.println("New .keystore file created!");
    }

    return keyStore;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be specific, are you looking for a location to store your private key, or the keystore?

In either case, though, the best place to store them should be your home folder (private keys by default are created in ~/.ssh/ on *nix systems).
The private key/ keystore must have restrictive permissions such that only you (the owner of the store) has read access to it (On *nix systems, this should translate to permissions 0400).

Comment: Thanks Mahesh... System.getProperty("user.home") right ?? Just top of it .. Will the linux system or windows system will not impact with this line... right ??? I mean i dont have to bother about the OS when I am putting file in home directory.....

Comment: Short answer, yes.